# Wit.ai to IBM watson migration

Tags: ibm-watson, chatbot, wit.ai, watson-conversation, facebook-chatbot

I want to import Wit.ai exported bot json data to IBM watson conversation workspace. Is there a tool available or any process that can help me to convert Wit.ai json data to be converted into json data required by Watson.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking. I'm not aware of any tool. I would recommend to create a simple Wit app then export it to understand how the json files are structured. Then you will create a script to migrate your IBM export in these files. Finally use this zip command before importing into a new wit app

```
zip FlowBased_SimpleExample.zip FlowBased_SimpleExample/app.json FlowBased_SimpleExample/entities/*.json FlowBased_SimpleExample/actions.json FlowBased_SimpleExample/stories.json FlowBased_SimpleExample/expressions.json
```

Comment: can you suggest me any kind of mapping that we can use to relate Wit data to Watson

Comment: Im not sure if wit defines the json schema, but the watson schema is defined in the api explorer.
https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/conversation-v1?cm_mc_uid=74153678844514869639761&cm_mc_sid_50200000=#!/workspaces/post_v1_workspaces
The hardest part will likely be the dialog piece as wit uses stories which are quite different than Watson's dialog tree. 
you may want to just migrate your intents/entities, and rebuild your dialog by hand.

Comment: My answer to converting DialogFlow to IBM Watson applies here too https://stackoverflow.com/a/53100912/810125