# Importing dialogflow intents and entities to IBM conversation workspace

Tags: dialogflow-es, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have an exported intents & entities zip file from Dialogflow workspace and tried to import this to IBM Watson workspace its not working is there anyway we could do this ?

Is there any methods we could use to migrate intents from Dialogflow to IBM Watson workspace?

Answer (score 3):

Check out a web app called QBox, it's primary purpose is to benchmark your training data, but it also lets you benechmark against multiple providers. If you run a test by uploading your DialogFlow training data, and select IBM Watson as output, you'll get an option on the resut page to download the training data in IBM Watson format.

[Select Watson after you've uploaded your training data](https://youtu.be/FZ30eBLHX3E?t=4):
[image: Select IBM after you've uploaded your training data]

Run the test, wait a few minutes, and on the results page use the menu on the top right to get your Watson formatted training data:

[image]

(Disclaimer: this is a tool I work on, so I have not provided a link, but if you Google the name 'Qbox' along with the term 'chatbot', you should find it!)

Answer (score 1):

DialogFlow is a different product than Watson Assistant. Watson Assistant only allows you to import a workspace that was exported from Watson Assistant (using the export workspace option in the UI) so Assistant is not able to import the dialog from DialogFlow.

You can download Intents and Entities in Watson Assistant in CSV format, see https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/intents.html#defining-intents and https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#defining-entities

You can import entities and intents in a CSV format, but they must be in the specific format that Assistant requires. See the previous 2 links.

Comment: Can we download intents and entities as CSV format ?

Comment: Watson Assistant allows you to import workspace, intents, entities, dialog though the workspace API.

Answer (score -1):

There is also this open source project `Watson Assistant Workbench (WAW)` that allows you to use a few additional formats to create your dialog with `Watson Assistant`.

`Watson Assistant Workbench` supports the `WA` `JSON` format, custom `XML` format and even MS `XLS` format which you can use to define your dialog. Then `WAW` can process all the data and generate a `JSON` that can be imported into `WA`.

This might simplify the conversation process as now you need to "only" convert dialog flow format into WAW XML or XLS (where you for example don't need to work with unique ids of the dialog nodes as in WA JSON format). 
So just sharing if this might be interesting - the [link to GitHub with Watson Assistant Workbench](https://github.com/IBM/watson-assistant-workbench).